# Understanding multiple network interfaces and routing using OpenWRT

Tags: networking

I have a single board computer running OpenWRT ([GW5100](http://www.gateworks.com/product/item/ventana-gw5100-network-processor)). I inserted a [wireless module](https://www.sierrawireless.com/products-and-solutions/embedded-solutions/em-and-mc-series/) to connect to Verizon's LTE network that looks like this:
[image]

After reading documentation from the manufacturer and from openwrt.org, my /etc/config/network file now looks like:

```
config interface 'loopback'
        option ifname 'lo'
        option proto 'static'
        option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
        option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config globals 'globals'
        option ula_prefix 'fda5:2ea8:8ced::/48'

config interface 'lan'
        option type 'bridge'
        option ifname 'eth0'
        option proto 'static'
        option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'
        option netmask '255.255.255.0'
        option ip6assign '60'

config interface 'wwan'
        option ifname 'wwan0'
        option proto 'dhcp'

config interface 'verizon'
        option ifname 'wwan0'
        option device '/dev/cdc-wdm0'
        option apn 'vzwinternet'
        option proto 'qmi'
        option delay '90'
```

loopback, globals, and lan were already in there by default. I added wwan and verizon. The board has an RJ45 jack, but nothing is plugged into it.

My build of OpenWRT appears to recognize the wireless module and exposed the appropriate devices in /dev according to the documentation. I've also verified my SIM card is registered correctly on Verizon's network. Unfortunately, I'm not getting an ipv4 IP address on the wwan0 interface.

My questions here are mostly about understanding the networking setup.

1. Since I added the new interface, should I expect it to "just work" as is? I tried running `udhcp -i wwan0`, but it just times out.
2. Why is eth0 contained within a bridge in /etc/config/network by default? What's the purpose of having a bridge with just one interface?
3. Do I need to add wwan0 to the bridge as well?
4. Do I need to manually add wwan0 to the routing table in this case? This is the entire output of `route`:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface  
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-lan
```